# Removing Scroll on Mobile and I pad devices in wordpress designing

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Create scroll on devices but while testing on Mozilla and chrome simulator don't create scroll please provide me solution to resolve scroll from all devices

http://projects.wbcomdesigns.com/vtc/all-courses

Comment: Its appearing scroll bar in all devices, including simulators, where is problem?

Comment: i want to remove scroll in all devices actually i have written body{overflow-x:hidden;} but it not works

Comment: you need to set it into `html` `html {overflow: hidden;overflow-y: auto;}`